# jQuery - only target class elements with same parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, parent

So i have a lot of profiles and thereby many divs which are repeated again and again
Now i want to target a class element with jquery and animate another class element in the same profile

```
in my case:
$(',profile_menu').click(function() {
  $( ".profile_like" ).removeClass( "m_hidden" )
  $(".profile_like").animate({
    left: 0+'%'
  },300);
```

The Problem is that i only want to target the classes which are in the same profile.

I hope that the issue has been well described.

```
<!-:::::::::::::::::::: Profile 1::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::-->
<div class="profile_box">
  <div class="profiles">
    <div class="profile_icons">
      <div class="profile_like m_hidden"></div>
      <div class="profile_favorite m_hidden"></div>
      <div class="profile_present m_hidden"></div>
      <div class="profile_chat m_hidden"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile_spacer"></div>
    <div class="info_container">
      <div class="info_bar">
        <div class="profile_name_spacer"></div>
        <div class="profile_name"></div>
        <div class="profile_city"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="profile_menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-:::::::::::::::::::: Profile 2::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::-->
<div class="profile_box">
  <div class="profiles">
    <div class="profile_icons">
      <div class="profile_like m_hidden"></div>
      <div class="profile_favorite m_hidden"></div>
      <div class="profile_present m_hidden"></div>
      <div class="profile_chat m_hidden"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile_spacer"></div>
    <div class="info_container">
      <div class="info_bar">
        <div class="profile_name_spacer"></div>
        <div class="profile_name"></div>
        <div class="profile_city"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="profile_menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-:::::::::::::::::::: Profile 3::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::-->
<div class="profile_box">
  <div class="profiles">
    <div class="profile_icons">
      <div class="profile_like m_hidden"></div>
      <div class="profile_favorite m_hidden"></div>
      <div class="profile_present m_hidden"></div>
      <div class="profile_chat m_hidden"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile_spacer"></div>
    <div class="info_container">
      <div class="info_bar">
        <div class="profile_name_spacer"></div>
        <div class="profile_name"></div>
        <div class="profile_city"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="profile_menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-:::::::::::::::::::: Profile 4::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::-->
...
...
...
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('.profile_box').find('.profile_like')`

Comment: @adeneo oh wow, relly easy. Thank you so much ! :)